# issue with $.proxy function , this not being passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to jQuery and just learning . I can across the $.proxy function in jQuery and decided to make a small programme using it but my code's not working , heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldtd5qeo/)(the keyboard events seem to having an issue in the fiddle , don't know why  !).

now if instead of $(this) in the if else construct, I directly use $('body') . my code works (I.E. the body element turns red).

also inside the function(e) if I console.log this , I get the `html` element , when instead the this should point to the `$('body')` .

below is my Jquery code :

```
$('body').on('keydown.bla.lalalal' , $.proxy(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 27) {
        $('body').addClass('red');
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('red');
    }
},this ));
```

I was just digging a plugin code too and found a similar function :

```
if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
    this.$element.on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
        e.which == 27 && this.hide()
    }, this))
} else if (!this.isShown) {
    this.$element.off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal')
}
```

I my syntax exactly almost matchs that of what I saw in that plugin code , but still my code , does't work , So what really am I missing ?

I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: There is no reason to use `$.proxy` here to get `this` referring to the BODY in the handler.

Comment: i want to use $.proxy , because i need to learn how proxy works , because i have to soon build a plugin that uses this function in abundance https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js .

Comment: This is how `$.proxy` works, hope this jsFiddle would help you better understand it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldtd5qeo/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry , but ur programme does't work , its giveing the same result as what was in my code , heres a screenshot , http://i.imgur.com/OJQ3z64.png  , the this points to the html , even inside the function .

Comment: But this is how it is supposed to work, setting context depending which element is passed to `$.proxy` method. And as in your code `this` is referring to HTML, then inside handler, `this` is referring to HTML

Comment: In your example, how are we supposed to know what `this` is that you're passing to `$.proxy`?  You need to show more context.

Comment: @JuanMendes , i will try to reframe my question .

Comment: instead of this, use $('body')  }, this)); => }, $('body')));

Comment: as @A.Wolff mentioned this depends on when you attach your function.  See my update http://jsfiddle.net/Ldtd5qeo/3/